# "MongoError: no primary found in replicaset" when trying to connect to mongodb database locally or through our galaxy server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-galaxy

I know this question has been asked before, but none of those solutions seem to have worked for me so far.

We've migrated our database over to and IBM cloud hosted mongoDB. I've got the connection working successfully for our .NET applications that use the Mongo.Driver library, but i can't get it work for our meteor app... Here's the connection string I have currently:

```
mongodb://admin:[PASSWORD]@url1.databases.appdomain.cloud:31928,url2.databases.appdomain.cloud:31928,url3.databases.appdomain.cloud:31928/dyo?authSource=admin;tls=true;tlsInsecure=true;connect=replicaSet;replicaSet=replset
```

I then run the connection string in this command:

```
SET MONGO_URL=[connection string shown above] && meteor --settings settings.json
```

And then we just get the error you see in the title over and over again. This happens on our galaxy server and locally. I feel like i should get this working locally first before deploying to our Galaxy server. Does anyone have any tips as to what could be happening here? I'm new to working with mongodb's and am at a loss

More info:

- MongoDB version: 4.4
- Meteor version: 1.4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing our connection issue by including `ssl=true` in the connection URL and removing all the parameters relating to TLS. I believe this has to do with our older version of meteor we are running, since ssl=true is actually deprecated later on...

Here's a github issue i also created if anyone has the same issue and needs more guidance in the future:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/12224